# EntityFramework Code First automatically setting the value of a public property

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, file-upload, ef-code-first

I am building a ASP.NET MVC 4 app that will allow users to upload a lot of images to the server. With each image certain entities will be associated, like the Product entity will be associated with the product images and the Category entity with the category images.

I am making a table in my schema to keep a record of all the uploaded files with a string 'Ref' which I will parse whenever the user wants to do an operation with the file, like deleting the file. That way when the user wants to delete the file I will simple mark the file in the schema for deletion and once a day I can 'sanitize' the server's uploaded files by deleting all the marked files in bulk.

For example a file `image.jpg` is uploaded as a product image, i will have in the ref tag `image productID 4` which indicates this is an image for a product with productID 4.

Is this the right way to implement handling of uploaded files or is there a better way to do it? Is this the right way to 'reference' the other entities associated with this file?

Here is my codefirst entity :

```
public class UploadedFile
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string RelativePath { get; set; }
    public string AbsolutePath { get; set; }
    public string Ref { get; set; }
    public DateTime UploadedOn { get; set; }
    public bool IsMarkedForDeletion { get; set; }
    public bool IsImage { get; set; }
}
```

Is there a way to declare certain public properties to be automagically set when other properties are set? For example I would like to add ImageWidth & ImageHeight property which are set automatically if the uploaded file type is an image (i.e. whenever I set IsImage = true)

Answer (score 0):

It is fine to use a Ref column, however it would be even more beneficial to have an additional column specifying the type of the reference, in your case it will be a product, but you might want to use the same table for references to different types of objects.

The logic of setting related properties shouldn't be part of the Model but rather the logic of the service that sets the IsImage property to true. So simply set other related properties there.